# I don't get the answer in this question, the marking scheme is bad?

Tags: functions

I have attached the 
[question](http://papers.xtremepapers.com/CIE/Cambridge%20International%20A%20and%20AS%20Level/Mathematics%20(9709)/9709_s13_qp_11.pdf) and 
[marking scheme](http://papers.xtremepapers.com/CIE/Cambridge%20International%20A%20and%20AS%20Level/Mathematics%20(9709)/9709_s13_ms_11.pdf) for May/June 2013 June A level examination paper.

In Question $1$, the question asked

It is given that $f(x)  =  (2x − 5)^3 + x$, for $x \in \mathbb{R}$  . Show that f is an increasing function.

However, in the marking scheme,  it says $$f'(x)=(2x-5)^2 \times 2+1$$ why?

The derivative should be $$3(2x-5)^2 \times 2 = 6(2x-5)^2$$ so where did the $\times2+1$ come from.

Also how do I prove that its an increasing question after that?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question for information on how to attract quality answers.

Comment: The first answer given $f^\prime(x)=2(2x-5)^2+1$ is incorrect, as you pointed out. But the second answer of $24\left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)^2+1$ is correct. It was evidently a typographical error.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Hi @JohnFire, I am including a link that helps you in improving maths typesetting.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Thank you will check it out

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales And how can I get that answer from =6(2x−5)2?

Comment: $6(2x-5)^2+1=6\left[2\left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)\right]^2+1=6(4)\left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)^2+1=24\left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)^2+1$.

Comment: Oh, so just complete the square. Alright, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x) = (2x-5)^3+x$$

Using chain rule,

\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\frac{d}{dx}(2x-5)^3 + \frac{d}{dx}x \\
&= 3(2x-5)^2\frac{d}{dx}(2x-5) +  1 \\
&= 3(2x-5)^2(2)+1 \\
&= 6(2x-5)^2+1 >0
\end{align}

Since the derivative is positive, it is an increasing function.

Edit: The $\times 2$ comes from chain rule when we differentiate $(2x-5)$.
 The $+1$ comes from $\frac{d}{dx}x$. Yes, there was a mistake in the marking scheme.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but you seem to have ignored the OP's actual question.

Comment: @mrnovice, thanks. Edited.  I wonder if I have answered the question.

Comment: I learned the chain rule as differentiating inside the bracked, and then the outside, I didn't know we have to add the x as well.

Comment: @JohnFire, in the original quesiton there is a $+x$ in the function definiton.

Comment: ... How could I miss that. Makes sense now, thank you :) 
So after differentiating I check if it's greater than 0, and if yes then the function is increasing?

Comment: Yes, positive derivative means strictly increasing.